# How do you get "style:" tag value in a Custom View

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-styles

In my custom view, I want to read a value of a `style` tag. For instance, my CustomButton could have `ButtonStyleLarge` or `ButtonStyleSmall`, and I need to read that value in my `init{ }` block

```
  <CustomButton
        style="@style/ButtonStyleLarge" // <- this one
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/User.Button.Save"/>
```

My custom view:

```
 class CustomButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
     context: Context,
     attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
     defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.ButtonStyleLarge
 ) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
 
     init {
         when (explicitStyle) {
             R.style.ButtonStyleLarge -> {
                 // do something to the view
             }
             R.style.ButtonStyleSmall -> {
                 // do something to the view
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

There is this function -> `getExplicitStyle()` (or just `explicitStyle` in Kotlin) but it is added in API 29. Need to support much lower SDKs.

Reading `defStyleAttr` at this point will just return the default value set in the constructor.

There is also an option for reading the "android" tag value like this (e.g. for maxLength):

```
attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "maxLength", 100)
```

Is there something similar for just `style`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get away by using `AttributeSet.getStyleAttribute()`

If this is your custom view

```xml
<CustomButton
    style="@style/MyStyle"
    ...
```

You can do this in the constructor

```kotlin
class CustomButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.ButtonStyleLarge
) : AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        // Retrieve style resource ID
        val explicitStyle = attrs?.getStyleAttribute() ?: NO_ID

        when (explicitStyle) {
            R.style.ButtonStyleLarge -> {
                // do something to the view
            }
            R.style.ButtonStyleSmall -> {
                // do something to the view
            }
        }

        // If you need the actual name of the Style resource...
        val styleName = context.resources.getResourceEntryName(explicitStyle)
        //  styleName = "MyStyle"

    }
}
```